# Lookup Column - Shows Some Additional Fields, But Missing Columns

Tags: list, list-view, lookup-column, tasks

I have created two related lists. The first list is keeps track of specific meetings, with the following:

- Name of meeting (Single Line Text)
- Date of meeting (Date and Time)
- Chair of meeting (Person)

The second list keeps track of meeting actions. Among other columns, each item in the action list contains a reference to the meeting the action was assigned in. I am able to use the lookup column feature to do this; I am also able to pull in the date of the meeting. However, it does not give me the option to pull in the meeting chair person.

I see that there are columns for `Created` and `Modified` which are people columns, but my specific `Chairperson` column does not come through.

Is there something I need to do differently to get the chairperson referenced on the view for the meeting actions?

Comment: Correction: `Created` and `Modified` are not people columns, they're date columns. You're thinking of `Created By` and `Modified By`, which, like `Chairperson`, are unavailable for selection as additional columns to show alongside a lookup column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is limitation. The additional fields cannot be of type Currency, Person, Lookup, Calculated, Custom Columns. See here for more information:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0753df63-8b30-4594-a8bd-ef8ba9514103/content-type-or-lists-lookup-column-cant-show-additional-fields-which-are-choice-or-lookup-columns?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Still this is a limitation on SharePoint Online ?